# Sharepoint REST api: wasn't $.Ajax supposed to make asynchronous calls?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, ajax, requestexecutor

I don't understand why my code is running synchronous. At least it is what the attached print-screen shows.
Are my assumptions correct?

```
<script src="../SiteAssets/js/lib/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.RequestExecutor.js"></script>

<script>
    var oWeb = "https://xxxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/edpsaomanoel/";

    $(document).ready(function () {
        getListItems();
        executorGetListItems();
    });

    var endpointUrl = "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('acoes')/items/?$select=Id,Title,DueDate,PercentComplete&$top=200";
    var acceptHeaders = {"Accept": "application/json; odata=minimalmetadata"}
    
    function onFail (data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
        console.log("Error:",errorMessage,errorCode,data);
    }

    function executorGetListItems() {   
        
        var executor;
        executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(oWeb);

        executor.executeAsync({
            url: endpointUrl,
            method: "GET",
            headers: acceptHeaders,
            error: onFail,
            success: function (data){
                console.log("ok executor",JSON.parse(data.body).value; //data.body.constructor === String     
                }
        });
    }

    function getListItems() {   
        
        $.ajax({
            url: oWeb + ""+ endpointUrl,
            method: "GET",
            headers: acceptHeaders,
            error: onFail,
            success: function (data){
                console.log("ok ajax",data.value); //data.value === Object
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

[image]

Comment: What happens if your return the Promise with ``return $.ajax(..)``, and what if you explicity set ``async:true``

Comment: Note: ``minimalmetadata`` is the default setting, so you can omit it. Or make the payload size even smaller with ``nometadata``: https://blogs.office.com/2014/08/13/json-light-support-rest-sharepoint-api-released/

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to query the same list simultaneously. Try two different lists. If you must query the list twice, return the promise of the ajax request. Then you can do something like:

```
$.when( getListItems(), executorGetListItems() )
.then(function(dataFromFirstFunction, dataFromSecondFunction){
     //do something
});
```

Which basically says when both functions are complete, then do something.